# how to check object exists() in Database-Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-views, try-except

I am trying to implement functionality where it will check the primary key (here in my case ID) in the database and if it is already present then It will not make any changes and its count is not considered. I have implemented it and it worked.

I am facing a problem what if the PK (ID )is not already present so for this I have tried to implement the check **`if x.exists():`** in  my code (here I have used try-except) but here try block is throwing an error.

Is there any way to implement without try-except for example by using **`if else`** where in **`if`**  block it will check **PK** present in Db or not if present update and increment stored variable value if not then ran **`else`** block code. So like it will check for all **`data`** in `imported_data`.

Please find the below Code.
**views.py**

```
---code---
----code---
    try:
            if current_time > '00:00:00' and current_time < '23:59:59':
                if len(count) <= 10000000:
                    if request.method == 'POST':
                        movie_resource = CTAResource()
                        dataset = Dataset()
                        new_movie = request.FILES['file']
                        if not new_movie.name.endswith('xls'):
                            messages.info(request, 'Sorry Wrong File Format.Please Upload valid format')
                            return render(request, 'app/uploadcts.html')
                        messages.info(request, 'Starting...')
                        imported_data = dataset.load(new_movie.read(), format='xls')
                        messages.info(request, 'Checking File content.')
                        for data in imported_data:
                            if data[1] != '' and (data[2] == 'Morning' or data[2] == 'Evening' or data[2] == 'General' or data[2] == 'Total'):
                                value = CTA(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7], data[8],)
                                x = CTA.objects.get(id=int(data[0]))
                                try: 
                                    if x.exists():
                                        if len(cts_general) <= general1 and data[2] == 'General' and data[2] != x.Shift_timing:
                                            print('Data ka Value', data)
                                            print('x ki value :', x.Shift_timing)
                                            cta_general.append(g)
                                            value.save()
                                            g = g + 1
                                            datax = data
                                            ldap.insert(1, datax)
                                            print('ldap list stored:', datax)
    
                                        elif len(cta_morning) <= morning1 and data[2] == 'Morning' and data[2] != x.Shift_timing:
                                            cta_morning.append(m)
                                            value.save()
                                            m = m + 1
                                            datax = data
                                            ldap.insert(1, datax)
    
                                        elif len(cts_evening) <= evening1 and data[2] == 'Evening' and data[2] != x.Shift_timing:
                                            cta_evening.append(e)
                                            value.save()
                                            e = e + 1
                                            datax = data
                                            ldap.insert(1, datax)
    
                                except:##If Id is new and not present in DB
                                    messages.info(request,'New Records')
                                    value.save()
    
                            else:
                                if data[1] == '':
                                    messages.info(request,
                                                  'Please Make Sure Username field value should not be blank. OR')
                                elif data[2] != 'Morning' or data[2] != 'Evening' or data[2] == 'General' or data[2] == 'Total':
                                    messages.info(request,
                                                  'Please check Shift Timing is other than Moring/Evening/General')
                                elif len(general) >= general1:
                                    messages.info(request,
                                                  'Soory General Shift Data Upload Limit has been reached! Please wait for Tomm.')
                                elif len(morning) >= morning1:
                                    messages.info(request,
                                                  'Soory Morning Shift Data Upload Limit has been reached! Please wait for Tomm.')
                                elif len(evening) >= evening1:
                                    messages.info(request,
                                                  'Soory Evening Shift Data Upload Limit has been reached! Please wait for Tomm.')
    
                                else:
                                    messages.info(request,
                                                  'Shift Timing Field is Empty or wrong string value.')
    
                                
                        else:
                            messages.info(request, 'File Processing')
                            messages.success(request, ". . . . .")
                            logger.info('Data present in CTA upload file:  %s !', imported_data)
                            messages.info(request, 'File is Uploded successfully')
                        print('Checking Data Type::', type(imported_data))
                        print('Imprted Data/order Its Value:::', imported_data)
                        print('LDAP ka data order**:::', ldap)
    
                        return render(request, 'app/uploadcta.html', {'ldap': [data[0:2] for data in ldap]})
    
                # return render(request, 'app/wrongtime.html')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Sorry,File Upload is not allowed')
    
        # return render(request, 'app/wrongtime.html')
        except:
            messages.info(request,
                          'Some Problem.')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the query is resulting into an exception due to the "*object.get*" method (CTA.objects.get()).

[QuerySet.get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) raise 2 errors in the following condition:

- No entry: Model.DoesNotExist
- Multiple entry: Model.MultipleObjectsReturned

In your case, it's throwing DoesNotExist exception when the PK is not present in the DB. To avoid use objects.filter(), [QuerySet.exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) should be able to check the condition you wish to check.

Comment: Hi I have used x = CTS.objects.filter(id=int(data[0])) but no luck still try block not excecuting.

Comment: not getting any error. except block is executing.

Comment: This has been resolved and I have used 
 y = CTS.objects.filter(EmailID=(data[3])).first()
 if y: 
             -----Logic
       if not y:
             -----Logic